# How to add a secquence of numbers after a specific text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Der
dsakj
asdsd
adsdaq
Spawn = 1
sdadsad
gwqsdas
dwqdsa
dasdwq
Spawn = 2.

Is there any command, that can make this happen?

Comment: What have you tried? Notepad++ isn't a scripting tool, so I don't think it is designed to do what you may be asking here.

Comment: I just thought it could make the Spawn 1 increase by one every time it's mentioned.

Comment: [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) should be able to do this.

Comment: I'm more asking of a command of code.